# Passing values to the Layout in Zend Framework.....?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am facing a problem in `zend-framework` related to `layout`. Here I have to `pass some values` to the `layout` that will be used to display the `top-ranking users` of the site.

Since I am new to zend-framework, I'm not able to find any way to do so.

If you have any code, idea or link, please provide me.....

Thanks in advance...........

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a Controller Plugin that fetches this data anytime before the layout is rendered and pass the data to to the view. Then render that data on your layout.phtml like you would render any other data, e.g. use a ViewHelper or a Partial.

See http://zendframework.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html

Or use an Action Helper as explained at

- http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets.html

Answer (score 2):

The layout in Zend Framework is just an other view. We could define the layout as the "outer view" and the view associated with a controller action as the "inner view". To send data to the layout from a controller you can simply like this

From the controller

```
$this->view->someData = $data
```

From the layout

```
$this->someData
```